# Errant URLs from an acquired site

Tags: seo, google-search-console, url

I recently acquired a website for an ecommerce company that I am now running, and am trying to get it up to snuff for SEO. It was previously a WordPress site but is now hosted on Shopify. I'm in the process of setting up my URL redirects and re-writing a lot of old content.

BUT when I go into my Google search console I see many many many (like over a thousand) pages that Google has crawled but not indexed (because of a 404 error) that I have no idea what they are or how they got there.

Here are a few representative examples:

- `https://www.example.com/xulwu/vital-smiles-birmingham%2C-al`
- `https://www.example.com/duh169/international-conferences-in-usa-2022-with-invitation-letter`
- `https://www.example.com/7srkots7/jolly-roger-menu-port-clinton`

I am not from Birmingham, I attend no international conferences, and I have never dined at the jolly roger.

What are these? How did they get associated with my domain? Should I be worried about them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the site was hacked at some point. If I search for [jolly-roger-menu-port-clinton using Google verbatim](https://www.google.com/search?q=jolly-roger-menu-port-clinton&num=30&tbs=li:1&filter=0&biw=1327&bih=1297&dpr=1.5#ip=1), I get tons and tons of pages of similar results from lots of different domains. If I click on them, they eventually redirect me to sites that look like they are paying for traffic through an affiliate program.

If the pages return 404 errors, you shouldn't need to worry about it, the hack has already been cleaned up. I'd just make sure that Google thinks they are 404 errors using the URL inspection tool in Google Search Console. Sometimes hacked sites only show their hacked content to search engine bots and clicks from search engines.

Google Search Console may continue to report that these URLs have been crawled forever. Googlebot doesn't seem to forget about pages on your site that once had something on them.